# NPM: Never install nested optional dependencies for npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm authoring a package A which I want to publish to NPM.

A has a dependency on package B, which in turn has a dependency on package C. C then has two optional native dependencies D and E. I know for definite I have no use for the optional dependencies, D and E, and NEVER want to try and install them when someone installs my package.

I know you can use the command `npm install A --no-optional -g` to install the package without optional dependencies, but this would be knowledge/overhead that I'd rather consumers of the package not need.

Is there any npm config or workaround where consumers of package A can just `npm install A` or `npm install -g A` and optional dependencies will never be installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install A --no-optional
```

Test to see if everything works.

```
npm list
```

Make sure you have no errors.

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

That will lock down the dependencies for the packages.

That way npm install will look into npm-shrinkwrap.json before trying to install dependencies.

You can read more about it here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap