# NPM List errors for missing dependencies of uninstall optional dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an npm project which needs to build on both Mac and Windows build servers. (This is for an Ionic mobile app, but I don't think that is relevant to my issue.) One of our dependencies has a dependency on `fsevents`, which is skipped by `npm install` on Windows machines. However, if I run `npm list --depth=0`, it is returning errors about missing dependencies of optional dependencies.

Minimal package.json to reproduce:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

Then I run `npm install`:

```
C:\temp\nodetest>npm install
...
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Notice that it skips `fsevents` because it does not support Windows OS.

Now I run npm list:

```
C:\temp\nodetest>npm list --depth=0
C:\temp\nodetest
`-- @ionic/app-scripts@3.2.3

npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
... (many other errors like this)
```

The errors are all due to dependencies of the uninstalled optional dependency. Is there any way to suppress these errors? I'm not seeing anything in the [npm list documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html).

My ultimate goal is to verify that all dependencies are installed, and fail the build otherwise. I'm currently using `npm list` to do that. Is there a better way to do this? We don't want to run `npm install` or `npm update` on every build, because we got many surprise bugs in the past when we did that.

I've also tried `npm list --depth=0 --no-optional` (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542712/npm-never-install-nested-optional-dependencies-for-npm-package)), but it doesn't look like `--no-optional` command is relevant to `npm list`.